# "Меньше (выше), чем". Нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*В 2017 году объем переработки нефти на белорусских НПЗ составил 18,1 млн тонн, что на 2,6% меньше чем в 2016 году.*
Нужна ли здесь запятая перед «чем»?

*Это выше, чем **было** в провальном 2016 году, когда цены на черное золото буквально обрушились, однако ниже, чем **было** в 2014-2015 году, когда белорусы закупали около 23 млн тонн нефти.*
Нужны ли здесь запятые перед словами «чем»?
Если выкинуть слова «было», запятые перед «чем» нужны/не нужны будут?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Во всех приведенных предложениях запятая перед союзом ЧЕМ ставится, так как в них присутствует **сравнение или сопоставление.**

Запятая не ставится в устойчивых выражениях при отсутствии сравнения или сопоставления.

Розенталь  [Пунктуация. § 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения. / Справочник по русскому языку](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146)

4. **Внутри сочетаний (не) больше чем, (не) меньше чем, (не) раньше чем, (не) позже чем и т. п., если они не содержат сравнения, запятая не ставится:** Вы были для меня больше чем другом;  Выпуск продукции увеличился больше чем вдвое;  Расчёты оказались более чем приблизительными;   Работу можно выполнить меньше чем за час;

**Но (при наличии сравнения или сопоставления):** Работает не меньше, чем другие; Гостей оказалось меньше, чем ожидали; Страдали от холода больше, чем от голода; Вернулся раньше, чем ожидали; Эта комната выше, чем соседняя;